When vue js token times out it gets stuck in loop
I'm working with vue js. when the token expires it loops when re-entering the login area
When the vue js token expires, it is entering the loop. I need to enter the program when I enter the login area without entering the loop and type login

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to post some code. No one will be able to help you with only this description.

Token, which one? Loops, where? Enter the program, which one? Type login? We gonna need a [repro] here.

VueApp.$router.push('/real-estate');
dispatch('initProfile', true);
